# playbook not checking the status of service for all the servers when using dynamic inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

```
- name: Check Agent Services
  hosts: all
  serial: 25
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: yes # speed up when we don't need to gather facts

  tasks:
  - name: Gathering service facts
    service_facts:
    register: services_state
  - debug: var=services_state.ansible_facts.services["besclient.service"].state
  - debug: var=services_state.ansible_facts.services["taniumclient.service"].state
  - debug: var=services_state.ansible_facts.services["filebeat.service"].state
  - debug: var=services_state.ansible_facts.services["ds_agent.service"].state
  - debug: var=services_state.ansible_facts.services["splunk.service"].state
  - debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
  - name: Gather Info
    become: false
    local_action: shell echo "{{ services_state.ansible_facts.services["besclient.service"].state | default('MISSING') }} {{ services_state.ansible_facts.services["taniumclient.service"].state | default('MISSING') }} {{ services_state.ansible_facts.services["filebeat.service"].state | default('MISSING') }} {{ services_state.ansible_facts.services["ds_agent.service"].state | default('MISSING') }} {{ services_state.ansible_facts.services["splunk.service"].state | default('MISSING') }} {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }} {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_fqdn'] }}" >> /tmp/result
```

```
ansible-playbook service_status.yaml -i ../dynamic_inventory/US/ -u xxxxx --ask-pass --ask-become-pass
```

I am using this playbook to check the status of the service, using dynamic inventory. Total 700+ servers will be there,out of that 226 server should respond to this playbook.

If I am using an inventory file with this 226 servers, result is copying to /tmp/result.

```
ansible-playbook service_status.yaml -i /tmp/inventory -u xxxxx --ask-pass --ask-become-pass
```

But when I am using dynamic inventory I am getting response from few servers(64). Do I need to enable anything in configuration?

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [172.15.17.150]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: no such identity: /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.176.155]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: no such identity: /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\r\nPermission denied (password,publickey,keyboard-interactive).", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.162.138]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.162.138 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.163.143]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.163.143 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.17.146]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.17.146 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.17.135]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.17.135 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.177.134]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.177.134 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.177.149]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.177.149 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.177.151]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.177.151 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.177.152]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.177.152 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.177.164]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.177.164 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.177.181]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.177.181 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.177.189]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.177.189 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.177.205]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.177.205 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.177.199]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.177.199 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}





fatal: [172.15.177.249]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.177.249 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.178.139]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.178.139 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.178.168]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.178.168 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.179.139]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.179.139 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.179.166]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.179.166 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.179.142]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.179.142 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.179.190]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.179.190 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.179.222]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.179.222 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.18.133]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.18.133 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [172.15.18.157]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.15.18.157 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}
```

Comment: Adding to the above issue:

I can see that playbook stopped after 25+ servers failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the above issue: I can see that playbook stopped after 25+ servers failure

Since you have added "serial: 25" in you playbook, ansible will execute on hosts in a batch of 25. Since your first batch itself is failing on ALL 25 nodes, play is failed.

> By default, Ansible will continue executing actions as long as there
> are hosts in the batch that have not yet failed

Refer : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html

About getting only 64 servers out of possible 226, is there any filers present in dynamic inventory file/script? Please post details about that.

Comment: I am using "aws_ec2" plugin to fetch the inventory. Now i have removed serial and all running in parallel now. waiting for the result. By default ansible have any failure percentage that is going to abort the play?